# How can I protect an environment with simple HTTP authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to push my application to heroku for testing, but I want to put simple HTTP authentication in front of it, so only I can access it.

What's the quickest & easiest way to do it?

Comment: Do you use any authentication in your app such as Devise or there is no authentication at all? One this is to disable devise sign up, and another thing is to place some kind of authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) A very basic authentication is built in [ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)

The way to start is

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret"
end
```

2) Another more Heroku oriented option is to use add-on [wwwhisper](https://addons.heroku.com/wwwhisper).

Answer (score 2):

[Give a person a fish and he eats for a day, teach him to fish and he eats every day](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication?view=comments)

Comment: Give him a fishing line that might break at any point and he might starve. [answer] _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: That's right, my apologies. but it's **obvious** don't googled first.